# Devise/Capybara Ambiguous match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber, capybara

I am using devise to create a sign up wizard,
but capybara(2.0.2) raises

```
Feature: Signing up
    In order to be attributed for my work
    As a user
    I want to be able to sign u

Scenario: Signing up
    Given I am on the homepage
    When I follow "Sign up"
    And I fill in "Email" with "user@ticketee.com"
    And I fill in "Password" with "password"
    Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching field "Password" (Capybara::Ambiguous)
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:10:in `/^(?:|I )fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/'
features/signing_up.feature:10:in `And I fill in "Password" with "password"'
    And I fill in "Password confirmation" with "password"
    And I press "Sign up"
    Then I should see "You have signed up successfully."
```

step definition is

```
When /^(?:|I )fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ do |field, value|
  fill_in(field, :with => value)
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In version 2.0 Capybara's `find` method raises a `Capybara::Ambiguous` exception when several elements matching specified locator where found. Capybara doesn't want to make an ambiguous choice for you.

The proper solution is to use another locator (e.g. `find('#id').set('password')` or `fill_in('field_name', with: 'password'`)

Read "Ambiguous Matches" section of [Capybara 2.0 Upgrade guide](http://techblog.fundinggates.com/blog/2012/08/capybara-2-0-upgrade-guide/) for a bit longer explanation of the same.

Answer (score 66):

With Capybara 2.1, this works:

```
  fill_in("Password", with: '123456', :match => :prefer_exact)
  fill_in("Password confirmation", with: '123456', :match => :prefer_exact)
```

From [here](http://www.elabs.se/blog/60-introducing-capybara-2-1) :prefer_exact is the behaviour present in Capybara 1.x. If multiple matches are found, some of which are exact, and some of which are not, then the first eaxctly matching element is returned.

Comment: fill_in("Password", with: '123456', :match => :first) is a good one too

Comment: Thank you. Surprised this solution doesn't show up more when googling these issues. In my opinion this should be the default behaviour. If I'm asking to fill something in, I'm usually being exact with the name.